# ActionLink Parameters always null - even with custom routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

The application manages requests. There is a ActionLink that should pass in the id of a request so it can be reset. The correct controller/action is called, but the request ID is always null.

If I change the last parameter of the custom route (shown below) to id="TEST", then "TEST" gets passed into the function - so I know the correct route is selected.

In controller BrowseController.cs

```
 [HttpGet]
 public ActionResult ResetRequest(string id )
 {
   return View();
 }
```

In View BrowseRequests.cshtml there is a link to reset a request

```
    @Html.ActionLink(
    "Reset", 
    "ResetRequest", 
    "Browse", 
    new {id = item.RS_RequestID.ToString() });
```

I've tried the default routing in RouteConfig.cs,  and then tried inserting the following before the default.

```
    routes.MapRoute(
       name:"ResetRequest",
       url:"Browse/ResetRequest/{id}",
       defaults: new { controller = "Browse", 
                       action = "ResetRequest", 
                       id=UrlParameter.Optional});
```

Comment: Does adding null at the end `new {id = item.RS_RequestID.ToString()}, null)` work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct overload for your ActionLink would be

```
HtmlHelper.ActionLink(string linkText,string actionName,string ControllerName, object routeValues, object htmlAttributes);
```

so you are missing object htmlAttributes which you can pass as null

```
@Html.ActionLink("Reset","ResetRequest","Browse", new {id = item.RS_RequestID.ToString() }, null);
```

Comment: Yes - this also works for me. As it is more complete explicit, I've opted to use this solution.  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

The order of the values you pass into ActionLink is not correct

use action, controller, routevalues , htmlArguments

Your first argument should be ResetRequest

Answer (score 0):

Your suggestion resulted in a "resource not found" error.  It did get me thinking that perhaps I was using the incorrect signature for the ActionLink.

I found an override that did not specify the controller - just the action. 
This is what worked for my purposes

```
    @Html.ActionLink(
      "Reset", 
      "ResetRequest", 
      new { id = item.RS_RequestID.ToString() });
```